# how to have a custom zsh auto_cd command

Tags: zsh, cd-command

Instead of the normal cd I've created my own function

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls -F
}
```

This works great for when I use commands like `cd someDir/subDir` but not when I change directories via zsh's auto_cd `someDir/subDir`.

Is there a way to customize what command gets called for `auto_cd`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical way to run-some-command-on-the-changing-of-the-directory is via the `chpwd` hook function (or list of functions named in the appropriately named `chpwd_functions` array):

```
% function chpwd () { pwd }  
% cd ~/tmp
/Users/jdoe/tmp
% pushd /etc
/etc ~/tmp
/etc
% chpwd_functions=( chpwd_do_ls )
% function chpwd_do_ls () { ls }
% cd /
/
Applications ...
```

Comment: `auto_cd` is an option, listed in `man zshoptions`.