# Oh My Zsh - execute ls after auto cd

Tags: zsh, ls, cd-command, oh-my-zsh

Oh My Zsh has this lovely feature where you can just type `dir-name` instead of `cd dir-name` to access the directory called `dir-name`.

In my old `.bashrc` I had a function that overwrites the builtin `cd` function such that every time I would `cd` into a directory, `ls` would be called in that directory.

However, this only works if I explicitly call `cd dir-name`.

Is there a way to do this in Oh My Zsh such that every time I access a directory by typing its name, `ls` will be called in that directory?

Comment: "Automatic `cd`" is a feature of `zsh`, not specifically of OMZ. It's enabled with `setopt AUTO_CD` or by starting the shell with the `-J` option. With `AUTO_CD` enabled, the actual `cd` command is never called, which is why overriding `cd` with a function or alias doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to have a custom zsh auto\_cd command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288548/how-to-have-a-custom-zsh-auto-cd-command)